# How convolution kernels are defined?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, filtering, convolution

I am currently learning some of the kernels that can be used for image preprocessing. I can see that every kernel that we use have some predefined values for n*n matrix as stated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)

But what I wanted to understand is how are these kernels defined? Why we end up having values as stated in Wiki.

Please do help me in understanding this. Thank you in advance

Comment: This is really a broad question. You can define millions of different convolution kernels, it is not possible to enumerate and explain them all. Understanding a convolution kernel requires understanding Fourier analysis, I recommend that you find a book about that. For example [Oppenheim and Willsky](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0138147574/) is a solid choice.

Comment: yes Cris. I feel this as a broad question. So the kernel derived is not done using Convolution Neural network backpropagation ?

Comment: Ha! Interesting! I didn't expect that point of view... :)  No, typically convolution kernels are designed for their desired properties. In a CNN, you get kernels that are designed by back propagation, but those kernels are specific to one network, and trying to understand their properties would be futile.

Comment: So I need to understand fourier to do this. But I have some question popping up. If the gaussian blurring, or any other kernel matrix are defined which can be applied to spatial domain. But when converting the image using fourier we are directly converting them into frequency domain right? In that case, how convolution can be done? because as far as I searched in google, convolution in spatial domain is equal to product in frequency domain. SInce the kernel are for spatial domain, how come fourier analysis comes into picture?

Comment: A convolution can be designed in the frequency domain (f.i. lowpass filtering makes a blurring effect), but applied in the spatial domain via a convolution.

Comment: Yes, convolving an image with a kernel can be done in the Fourier domain by transforming both, multiplying them, then inverse transforming the product. Because of this relationship, the Fourier domain is a great way to analyze and design linear filters: there the simple multiplication is easy to understand, you see what happens to each individual frequency component.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will take a look into this